# Programatically Instantiate asp.net page, and its controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, automation

I have an asp.net page, with methods making use of controls on the page. I have a need to instantiate this page, automate some "user interaction", selecting a radio button, clicking a button etc.

For the most part this works, but I have to physically instantiate every control I want to use like this programmatically. Is there a method/technique for instantiating all the controls, as gets done when the page "loads" before it gets sent to the browser?

```
Dim myTempForm As New form1

mytempForm.label1 = "demo text" <--- label1 is Nothing --- object reference not set

mytempForm.label1 = new Label 

myTempForm.label1 = "demo text" <-- now works as expected, I can use it...
```

I suppose and can go ahead an instantiate all the controls, but this is a temporary automation that I need to do, I'd wish not to have to instantiate everything.

Is there a method I can call to "build" the page, if you will? I suppose I am looking or the opposite of dispose? Calling init does not help, as this does not psychically create the controls.

This will probably do the job.. but is there a better way?

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf (Control) Is Label Then
        Control = New Label
    ElseIf TypeOf (Control) Is Panel Then
        Control = New Panel
    ElseIf TypeOf (Control) Is TextBox Then
        Control = New TextBox
    ElseIf TypeOf (Control) Is RadioButton Then
        Control = New RadioButton
    ElseIf TypeOf (Control) Is Button Then
        Control = New Button
    ElseIf TypeOf (Control) Is UpdatePanel Then
        Control = New UpdatePanel
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using my code block in the original question.